# Connecting ubuntu AWS instance to desktop view using RDP

Tags: aws, rdp

I have ubuntu AWS instance. I am trying to connect to desktop view using RDP.
For this, i have followed below mentioned steps:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y ubuntu-desktop xrdp
cat /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
[globals]
bitmap_cache=yes
bitmap_compression=yes
port=3389
crypt_level=low
channel_code=1
max_bpp=24
#black=000000
#grey=d6d3ce
#dark_grey=808080
#blue=08246b
#dark_blue=08246b
#white=ffffff
#red=ff0000
#green=00ff00
#background=626c72

[xrdp1]
name=sesman-Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1

[xrdp2]
name=console
lib=libvnc.so
ip=127.0.0.1
port=5900
username=na
password=ask

[xrdp3]
name=vnc-any
lib=libvnc.so
ip=ask
port=ask5900
username=na
password=ask

[xrdp4]
name=sesman-any
lib=libvnc.so
ip=ask
port=-1
username=ask
password=ask

[xrdp5]
name=rdp-any
lib=librdp.so
ip=ask
port=ask3389

[xrdp6]
name=freerdp-any
lib=libxrdpfreerdp1.so
ip=ask
port=ask3389
username=ask
password=ask

[xrdp7]
name=sesman-X11rdp
lib=libxup.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
xserverbpp=24

sudo service xrdp restart
```

After this,for connecting via RDP, i use public DNS for connecting.
  If i chose sesman-X11rdp in modules, the message is shown as connected OK, but screen doesnt appears.
  If i chose rdp-any in module, a disturbed screen appears for 2 seconds nad then disappears.

I have already added RDP rule in security policy of instance. What am i doing wrong. What do i need to do to connect properly via RDP?

Comment: Have you setup a desktop first on your Ubuntu instance? By default Ubuntu instances in AWS do not have a desktop. You connect via SSH to a terminal (TTY) session.

Comment: No, i haven't set up a desktop first. A few days ago, I raised request in AWS support and got the link to this document  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-to-linux-desktop-from-windows/  , and was able to launch desktop successfully, But i am unable to access this link now, so trying RDP and getting errors, Also tried nomachine as suggested on other sites, but no luck